# non-last children applies the CSS style defined by :last-child

Tags: html, css

I just found if the CSS class is defined by children selector e.g. ':last-child', the non-last children will be applied the class unexpectedly. span.item is also a child of div.list in my opinion, just not a direct one. My code is as below. So does :last-child, :first-child and nth-child only work for the direct children? If true, is there a way to make it work as expected?

```
<style>
.list .item {
    color: green;    
}
.list .item:last-child {
    color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="list">
    <p class="item">Clothes</p> <!-- GREEN -->
    <p class="item">Shoes</p> <!-- RED -->
    <p><span class="item">Clothes</span></p> <!-- RED, which is expected to show green text -->
    <p><span class="item">Shoes</span></p> <!-- RED -->
</div>
```

---

Added more. Thanks everybody who replies. the example I offered here is a very simple one, in fact I met a more complex case in my work. In the case the class 'item' has to be applied to descendent elements rather than direct children. I can make current sample more complex here.

```
<style>
.list .item {
    color: green;
    padding: 10px;
}
.list .item:last-child {
    color: red;
}

.item-detail {
    color: yellow;
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>

<div class="list">
    <p class="item">Clothes</p> <!-- GREEN -->
    <p class="item">Shoes</p> <!-- RED -->
    <p class="item-detail">
        Show detailed info of following item. <!-- YELLOW-->
        <span class="item">Clothes</span> <!-- RED, which is expected to show green text -->
    </p>
    <p><span class="item">Shoes</span></p> <!-- RED -->
</div>
```

Comment: *"span.item is also a child of div.list in my opinion"* That's where you are wrong. `span.item` is a **descendant** of `div.list`. The `p` elements are the children of the `div.list` element. The child of your child is not your child. It's your grandchild, your descendant.

Comment: Apart from the confusion about the meaning of `:last-child` (for which the specifications should be consulted), the question describes some cases, in a partly mistaken way, and does not describe *what should happen*, i.e. which elements should be matched by a selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with `:last-child` or say `:last-of-type` is that they do not respect classes...

As I see the pattern here, you are trying to apply the colors alternately, so you can use `nth-of-type(even)` pseudo

```
.list p:nth-of-type(even) {
    color: red;
}

.list p {
    color: green;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2jxtg/)

---

Now I will explain how your selectors work, you have this `.list .item` means it will apply the colors to `p` and `span` which are nested inside an element having `class` of `.list`.

Fine, about the second selector which is `.list .item:last-child` will select the last child which are nested inside `p` element. As I said, it won't respect the classes... So as `span`are the `last-child` inside `p`, they will be selected.

---

If you are willing to change your markup, then, wrap the `p` elements inside `div`

**HTML**

```
<div class="list">
    <div>
        <p class="item">Clothes</p> <!-- GREEN -->
        <p class="item">Clothes</p> <!-- GREEN -->
        <p class="item">Shoes</p> <!-- RED -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="item">Clothes</p> <!-- GREEN -->
        <p class="item">Shoes</p> <!-- RED -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list > div p:last-child {
    color: red;
}

.list p {
    color: green;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2jxtg/10/)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually expected: your `<span class="item">` are the last child of their parent (see [this article on css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/).

The *Shoes* `p` is also the last child of its parent with class `item` and thus should be affected.

Oddly enough, when testing the code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBXLL/), I see the *Shoes* in green when I would have expected to see it as red like you apparently see it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's relative to it's parent. In this case it's inside a p element. so span.item is the first and last child. So both of the span.item inside the p elements are red.

If you wanted the last item to be red, whether it's a p or a span inside a p, use this:

```
.list p:last-child, .list p:last-child span {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **[:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child)** CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the last child element of its **parent**.

For `<p><span class="item">Clothes</span></p>`,  `<span class="item">Clothes</span>` is the last child element of its parent, which is the `<p>` element.

Just define the `class` on `<p>` and it will work as you expect:

```
<div class="list">
    <p class="item">Clothes</p> 
    <p class="item">Shoes</p>
    <p class="item"><span>Clothes</span></p>
    <p class="item"><span>Shoes</span></p> <!-- RED -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.list .item {
    color:green;    
}
.list .item:last-child{
    color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="list">
    <p class="item">Clothes</p> <!-- GREEN -->
    <p class="item">Shoes</p> <!-- RED -->
    <p class="item">Clothes</p> <!-- RED, which is expected to show green text -->
    <p class="item">Shoes</p> <!-- RED -->
</div>
```

Got it?